# Error at renew SSL with certbot at Digital Ocean

Tags: linux, debian, ssl

i have a problem with text value of TXT on Digital Ocean,
i used nslookup and return:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find _acme-challenge.example.com.br: No answer
```

On CertBot after press enter to validate TXT value:

```
Domain: example.com.br
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.example.com.br
```

I try reduce time TTL, but have fail.